# high memory & cpu usage in ffmpeg C sample when muxing audio and video

Tags: c, windows, ffmpeg

I am using the `muxing.c` example provided with ffmpeg 3.0 version to create an MP4 file (H.264 & AAC) with VS 2013.

The sample is working fine with default width & height for video, but when I changed the width to 1920 and height to 1080, the sample is taking nearly 400MB & 60-70% cpu usage (using task manager & in Release mode) throughout the program. I have used multi threading also.

I tried to free the encoded packet after calling `write_frame()`, but to no success.
The memory is being released only after calling `avcodec_close()`.

Could anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I am adding link (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B75_-V7se7tmWUhyM0ItS0kzUVk) to code I tested with VS 2013.

The screenshot link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B75_-V7se7tmVm4tUjFtSnNNSHc

The `STREAM_DURATION` value in the sample is set to 120 seconds (even tested with 600 seconds) and I changed default Height & Width values of **AVCodecContext** in `add_stream` function for video type to 1080 & 1920 respectively. Through out program, it is taking 355 MB, not changing at all. I think, once frame is encoded using `avcodec_encode_video2` and written to the file, the memory should be released.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve) and follow the guidance there to post a properly qualified question.

Comment: Why do you assume something is wrong? How much memory and CPU do you believe it should use?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete the already rendered frame, you still need it for the next frames. It's how compressions works for the H.264 codec and many others: check what changes between individual frames and replace everything that does not change with some code that says: *ibid* (yes, it's a lot more complicated than that).

But the memory usage is quite modest with ffmpeg version 3.0.2:

Run with 288x352 and a 10s stream (the defaults):

```
==9162== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9162==     in use at exit: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==9162==   total heap usage: 19,970 allocs, 19,969 frees, 4,036,822 bytes allocated
==9162== 
==9162== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==9162==    at 0x4C2D110: memalign (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9162==    by 0x4C2D227: posix_memalign (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9162==    by 0xDB7B49: av_malloc (mem.c:97)
==9162==    by 0x97EE51: default_lockmgr_cb (utils.c:77)
==9162==    by 0x9854F6: ff_lock_avcodec (utils.c:3320)
==9162==    by 0x985733: avcodec_open2 (utils.c:1197)
==9162==    by 0x4674F8: open_video (muxing.c:392)
==9162==    by 0x4674F8: main (muxing.c:595)
==9162== 
==9162== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9162==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9162==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9162==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9162==    still reachable: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==9162==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9162== 
==9162== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9162== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

(Oh, look Ma', a memory leak!)

With full-hd (1920x1080, which is more than 20 times larger!)

```
==9402== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9402==     in use at exit: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==9402==   total heap usage: 19,970 allocs, 19,969 frees, 25,695,760 bytes allocated
```

These are the same number of allocation but for 25mb of memory—21mb more for an over 20 times larger format seems apt.

Extending the duration to 120s:

```
==9459== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9459==     in use at exit: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==9459==   total heap usage: 236,157 allocs, 236,156 frees, 84,057,359 bytes allocated
```

And, finally 600s:

```
==9821== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9821==     in use at exit: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==9821==   total heap usage: 1,179,521 allocs, 1,179,520 frees, 340,106,248 bytes allocated
```

Seems reasonable to me.

It is probably a matter of the exact version of ffmpeg not Windows, because an older snapshot (from April) showed the same extensive use of memory like your version does.

The ChangeLog is a bit sparse, I only found the entry

- avformat/cache: Fix memleak of tree entries

in 3.0.1, so you need to search the [GIT](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg) to get more information.